# How to create a DLL from a WSDL for use in DNN Module

Tags: asp.net, dll, wsdl, dotnetnuke

I'm creating a DNN 4.9.5 module and need to create a DLL from a WSDL (Doba API).  I've created a separate Class Library project in my DNN solution with Class1.vb in it.  What do I need to include in my class from the WSDL file?  Obviously, I won't be going with Class1.vb, but just need a gentle push as to how to get this going.

Thanks much for your guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem. Simply create your class library and then use "Add Service Reference" to point to the WSDL.

Do not use "Add Web Reference" unless you have to. Microsoft considers that to be "legacy technology".

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to create a dll to access the webservice? If you just want to use it (assumung that you are using ms-visualStudio) you need to **add a webservice reference** to your separate Class Library project .

That will create the sourcecode for a wrapper class to call the webservice described by wsdl.
See [msdn:How to: Add and Remove Web References](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9w023sx%28VS.80%29.aspx)